# dnscmd equivalent on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, domain-name-system

I want to add an entry to a remote dns server. I have Windows 7 32bits without dnscmd.
So I am looking for some dns client application that would implement the same functionality as dnscmd on Windows 7.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The thing to do is to install SP1 and then [Windows
Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7887)
. To enable the DNSCMD binary, after installation it's necessary to enable Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Remote Server Administration Tools -> Role Administration Tools -> DNS Server Tools.